# Issue when I groupby & fill na with the min date value by the grouped element

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

This is the my dataset and I am trying to fill the date columns that have NaN with min value.

[image]

I am trying to fill the NaN in the date columns with the min from that date column for the ag_id (grouped-by element). When I do the below I get unexpected output.

```
df_test_revenue_1["1st_rev_month"] = df_test_revenue_1.groupby("ag_id").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.min()))
```

Unexpected output from executing the above :

[image]

I was expecting all the values of the column `1st_rev_month` to be `2017-10-01`. Instead it looks like it it picking the values for `1st_rev_month` from column `revenue_month`

My end goal is to get this result (apple the same logic to rest of the date columns (except `revenue_month` column
[image]

Comment: post text, not screen shots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```py
df_test_revenue_1.groupby("ag_id").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.min()))
```

never refer to column "1st_rev_month". your refer to it on the left hand side, means "put the result in the 1st_rev_month" column. But what is result? it's minimum over all dataframe, not just over "1st_rev_month".

You need to take the minimum only over "1st_rev_month" column.

The fix:

```py
df_test_revenue_1["1st_rev_month"]=df_test_revenue_1.groupby("ag_id")['1st_rev_month'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.min()))
```

adding `['1st_rev_month']` after groupby to take only relevant column